# gmaps4rails: Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I want to inclued maps into my rails application (I am using Rails 3.2.11 with asset pipeline) via the Gmaps4Rails gem. Following the setup instructions for this gem on https://github.com/apneadiving/ , I have

- included the gem in the Gemfile via `gem gmaps4rails`
- copied the assets to my rails app using the generator provided by the gem `rails generate gmaps4rails:install`. After doing that, there is the `gmaps4rails.css` in the `app\assets\stylesheets`folder and 5 coffeescripts in the àpp\assets\javascripts\gmaps4rails` folder
- included the Javascripts via `<%= yield :scripts %>`. Side-question: Is it sufficient to put this btw. the closing body and the closing html tag, or should there be a footer tag used where the Javascripts are yielded?

  ```
    ...
    </body>
    <%= yield :scripts %>
  </html>
  ```

Model, migrations, etc. are all set up and should work. 
Finally, in the view, I am calling `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>`.

Unfortunately, I get a JavaScript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined`. The following screenshot shows how Chrome reports the error in the gmaps4rails Javascripts:

[image: Chrome reporting a JavaScript error on gmaps4rails]

The result is that the map is not rendered with any concent; there's just the CSS wrapper for the map but without any content.

I am not able to fix this, so I need your support.

What I tried out and noticed so far:

- The two Javascripts from Google before the script where the error occurs seem to load dynamically and after the last Javascript is loaded. I have downloaded the JavaScripts directly from the source, built local files out of them, and included the into the assets pipeline, however, this did not resolve the issue.
- I assume that Gmaps (which cannot be referenced) has been renamed in the previous loaded library Javascripts. However, as I don't know how this works in detail, I cannot follow up here and check it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I missed to add the gmaps4rails Javascripts properly to the asset pipeline.

Adding either

```
    //= require_tree .
```

or

```
    //= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing
    //= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
    //= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.mapquest
    //= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers
    //= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
```

to application.js would fix the issue.

However, as it seems that I have forgotten to add

```
    //= require_tree .
```

completely, I have added it just as the last of the includes to my application.js.