# Heroku production : Gmaps is not defined - works in local

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmaps4rails

On a simple page, I show a google map with one marker.

In local, everythings works perfectly but, on Heroku I got an error in console :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined
```

this is related to

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google'); //and some other stuff
```

Localy, this is working. But when I deployed this on heroku, it's like it can't load the JS.

this is on the top of my file

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

and the `application.js`

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

I'ts probably a simple error, maybe related to assets precompiled, but I'm not really an expert in this area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I solved my problem :

My console showed me that JQuery was not defined. I didn't really pay much attention to it. But this was the problem. So I **change the order of the requires** in my `application.js` and i put **gmaps** in the top

```
//= require gmaps/google
//= require jQuery.headroom.min.js
//= require headroom.min.js    
//= require underscore
//= require template.js
```

so gmaps in the top of the file, When JQuery is declared undefined It didn't block gmaps to load.
So now I have to fix the jquery problem, but this gmaps problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

When u run the rails server in your local system always use the command "rails s -e production" to check how the site works in heroku.  You should probably add

> //= require_tree .

to your application.js.. Please check the following link :

[gmaps4rails: Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766366/gmaps4rails-uncaught-referenceerror-gmaps-is-not-defined)

If you have got the error by using standard `<script>` on a .html.erb  file then this is how you include javascript on you .html.erb file otherwise it might show errors

`<%= javascript_include_tag "http://YourJavascriptFileLink.js" %>`

Comment: I added this at the end of my application.js, but nothing change.
But actually, I don't really use gmaps4rails, I use Gmaps (froms the scripts) and I don't think this comes from the application.js, It juste seems like heroku doesn't load theses 3 script googlemaps on the top of my file

Comment: can u share link to your repository ?? i will run and check it on my local rails server. Maybe i can help.

Comment: use this line in your html.erb file rather than the normal html usage.. maybe that is the problem.

`<%= javascript_include_tag "https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js" %>`